# Certificate Signing Request (CSR) - Company name

Tags: ssl, https, server, ssl-certificate

I searched on Internet a lot about this topic but I couldn't fine the exact answer.

My question is: Is it mandatory to have an organization or company in order to make a CSR?

Most of the fields needed to make a CSR are information about an organization such as organization's name, location, etc.

What should I do if I want to have a ssl on my domain but I am not part of an organization?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you request a simple domain validation (DV) certificate, you shouldn't provide an organization (and if you did, the organization information will be ignored or the csr will be rejected).

If you ask for an Extended Validation (EV) certificate or an Organization Validation (OV) certificate, as the certificate attest the ownership of the domain by an organization, you need an organization.

Comment: Thank you so much!! So, if I want a simple domain validation, living those fields about the organization in blank  would be enough to build a CRS?

Comment: @LeandroOcampo yes !

Answer (score 1):

It isn’t necessary to have organization name in the terms of CSR generation.

But without organization information, you can request only domain validation (DV) certificates. It will verify your control over the domain name and issue your certificate within a few minutes.

To obtain organization validation (OV) or extended validation (EV) SSL certificate, you must have organization information and related documents to prove the reliability of the company.

Comment: To prove the *identity* of the company. Certificates don't guarantee reliability, and neither does anything else really.

Comment: CAs has to verify the identity of the company and they are liable to prove business authentication before issuing the certificate. Even they are offering extended warranties with their SSL certificate products - https://www.symantec.com/content/en/us/about/media/repository/netsure-protection-plan.pdf